# Using foreign key in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table inside my database named categories:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` 
( `categoryName` varchar(128)  ,
 `subcategoryName` varchar(128) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`categoryName`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A category in this table may be a subcategory of another category in this field.So,subcategory is a FK to categories.Initialiasiation:

```
    ALTER TABLE `category` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`subcategoryName`) 
REFERENCES `category`(`categoryName`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

So i tried inserting values in this table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`categoryName`, `subcategoryName`) VALUES
( 'Literature','Satire'),
( 'Science','Mathematics'),
( 'Science','Physics');
```

but i get this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`php_beginner_crud_level_1`.`category`, CONSTRAINT `category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategoryName`) REFERENCES `category` (`categoryName`))
```

I think this means that i can't isent a subcategory if the category does not already exist.So what i did is insert first single categories:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`categoryName`) VALUES
( 'Literature'),
( 'Mathematics'),
( 'Programming');
```

Hw can i insert subcategories for these categories now?
for example if i want a subcategory: Java for Programming how can i insert it into the table?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you called them `categoryName` and `parentCategoryName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the foreign key relationship backwards. Subcategories reference categories, so it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `category` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`categoryName`) 
REFERENCES `category`(`subcategoryName`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

And the primary key should be `subcategoryName`, not `categoryName`.

You need to create subcategories with no category for the top-level categories in the hierarchy.

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`categoryName`, `subcategoryName`) VALUES
(NULL, 'Literature'),
(NULL, 'Science'),
( 'Literature','Satire'),
( 'Science','Mathematics'),
( 'Physics','Science');
```

Or rename things to make more sense.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` 
( `categoryName` varchar(128)  NOT NULL,
 `supercategoryName` varchar(128) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`categoryName`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `category` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`supercategoryName`) 
REFERENCES `category`(`categoryName`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

INSERT INTO `category` (`categoryName`, `subcategoryName`) VALUES
(NULL, 'Literature'),
(NULL, 'Science'),
('Literature', NULL),
('Science', NULL),
( 'Satire','Literature'),
( 'Mathematics','Science'),
( 'Science'',Physics');
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.It is for a school exercise and it specificaly says subcategory is a FK to category?

Comment: This can't be done with subcategoryName being the foreign key?Moreover,can categoryName be both primary and foreign key at the same time?

Comment: No, it can't, because a category can have more than one subcategory. Maybe it's supposed be `subcategoryOf`?

Comment: You have no `Satire` category in your table, so you can't have a FK that references it.

Comment: if i use supercategoryName istead of subcategoryName?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. I mentioned that in a comment.

Comment: thank you sir.Would the code be the same as your solution but instead of subcategoryName  put supercategoryName?

Comment: Yes, although the order of values would be reversed. `('Satire', 'Literature')`

Comment: i did as you said but still if supercategoryName is the foreign key i cannot seem to be able to insert values.Could you please update the answer for this?